# Remove Duplicate Rows MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, duplicates, navicat

I have been trying to delete duplicate rows from a table but all my efforts either result in error or get stuck during execution. 
My Table has 16.8 million records including 1.5 million duplicates.
Table structure is as follows

```
--------------------------------------
| id | number | city | region | site |
--------------------------------------
| 1  | 12345  | abc  | xyz    | 321  |
| 2  | 67890  | def  | axc    | 167  |
| 3  | 12345  | abc  | xyz    | 321  |
| 4  | 13400  | fff  | aaa    | 301  |
--------------------------------------
```

I have tried using some of the approaches suggested in answers here at stack overflow but couldn't find a solution that worked for me.

```
DELETE n1 FROM data n1, data n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.number = n2.number
```

Didn't work so I tried following:

```
DELETE FROM data where data.number in 
(
    SELECT number from data GROUP BY number HAVING COUNT(*)>1
)
LIMIT 1
```

No use here either so I am stuck. All sorts of suggestions are welcome.

**THE SOLUTION THAT WORKED FOR ME**

Marc-B marked the post as duplicate of stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/1528290 tried that approach and it worked like a charm. 
my query was :

```
alter ignore table data add unique i_number (number)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30401571/how-to-remove-duplicate-row-considering-the-arabic-phonetics/30402156#30402156

Comment: @B-Abbasi .. Do you wish to delete all the occurrences of duplicate rows ? Or do you wish to keep a single row for each set of duplicate rows ?

Comment: Why did the `DELETE n1 FROM data n1, data n2 WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.number = n2.number` not work? What error was given?

Comment: You haven't actually defined what a duplicate record would be. The same number in any record? The same number for a city, region, site combination?

Comment: @DfrDkn I want to keep single row for each duplicate

Comment: dupes across columns 2,3,4,5, keeping min of id ? ie: keep id=1 kill id=3 in your dataset ?

Comment: @AndySavage duplicate rows have same value in all columns except ID which is a primary key.

Comment: @JohnnyStrings the query got stuck, had to kill the query

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the duplication is done on the `number` column. Try this:

```
DELETE FROM data 
 WHERE data.number NOT IN (SELECT * 
                    FROM (SELECT MAX(data.id)
                            FROM data n
                        GROUP BY data.number) x)
```

This will keep one record(which has the highest number) and delete the rest of the records in your table.

**EDIT:**

I just checked with your query and it worked for me:

```
DELETE n1 FROM foobarred n1, foobarred n2 
WHERE n1.id > n2.id AND n1.number = n2.number;
```

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/06ea5/1)

I guess you should follow Drew's comment: *on mysql workbench you have to close database, go to Edit / Preferences / SQL Editor / and @ bottom clear Safe Updates re-connect to server, select db, and fire it off above pastie*

Marc-B marked the post as duplicate of stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/1528290 tried this approach and it worked like a charm. 
my query was :

```
alter ignore table data add unique i_number (number)
```

Comment: O yes I totally forgot to write about this,I tried it and it deleted all the records from the table. Not sure why.

Comment: Duplicate rows are exact replicas of each other except ID which is the Primary Key

Comment: @B-Abbasi:- Updated my answer. Can you try now?

Comment: check this out: http://pastie.org/10212389

Comment: on mysql workbench you have to close database, go to Edit / Preferences / SQL Editor / and @ bottom clear Safe Updates

re-connect to server, select db, and fire it off above pastie

Comment: Marc-B marked the post as duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/3312066/1528290
tried this approach and it worked like a charm.
my query was : 
alter ignore table data add unique i_number (number)

Comment: @B-Abbasi:- Ok great. You can proceed with that. Happy coding. If you want then you can paste that as answer or else edit mine and accept that as answer!

Comment: I have tried your query and it is still executing, it is longer process than the one that worked for me. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: @RahulTripathi query from your answer executed without an error and deleted all the records once again. so I have unmarked its as not the answer